# Nanopb: add already encoded messages as a repeated field

Tags: protocol-buffers, nanopb

I have message of the form:

```
message OuterMessage {
  repeated InnerMessage msg = 1;
}
```

I would like to compose an instance of OuterMessage by appending already encoded instances of InnerMessage. Is there a legit way to do this with nanopbs?

Comment: if you are able to change the schema, maybe something like repeated bytes? However, you will loose the advantages of type check. If not, I would recommend that you check if the implementations of protocol buffers you work with have a way to create an object from bytes. This is called marshalling and unmarshalling.

Comment: You could look into using the any field type: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways:

1. Encode outer message manually by calling `pb_encode_tag_for_field()` and `pb_encode_string()`. In protobuf, submessages are equivalent to strings in [the wire format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding).
2. Use callbacks for the repeated field. In the callback you can do the same as 1. above, but also get automatic encoding of any other fields in the outer message.
3. Encode just the header (tag and length) to a separate buffer, send it and then send your already encoded message. This avoids having to copy the data around.
4. Set option `(nanopb).type_override = TYPE_BYTES` on the submessage field, to generate it as if was a `bytes` field instead. Then you can set the encoded content inside that. But this approach is quite inefficient, as it results in copying the message data multiple times.